# Nginx mail proxy hides client's ip

Tags: nginx, proxy, email-server, dovecot

I successfully set up nginx imap/pop3 mail proxy with auth_http which has been working fine for months.
Recently came up a request on showing client's IP in mail.log at imap logins.

Since Nginx communicates with Dovecot the IP address in log belongs to Nginx server (which in this case 127.0.0.1 - as they are on the same server).

So far I could not find a solution or workaround for that.
Apparently not even logging is possible in nginx mail block.

The closest hit was a HAProxy support in Dovecot (https://wiki2.dovecot.org/HAProxy) but I am not sure there is similar to Nginx.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure whether this also works when using nginx as an IMAP proxy (nor do I actually know how Dovecot itself transfers the client IP when used as a proxy), but you have to [configure the proxy as trusted network](https://wiki2.dovecot.org/PasswordDatabase/ExtraFields/Proxy?highlight=%28login_trusted_networks%29): "Set `login_trusted_networks` to point to the proxies in the backends. This way you'll get the clients' actual IP addresses logged instead of the proxy's."

Comment: Thanks Jens, in my understanding it applies when Dovecot does the proxying and login_trusted_networks contains the IP of the remote server, but here Dovecot IS the remote server.

Comment: No, `login_trusted_networks` is required to contain the proxy server in the backend server's configuration. There are different effects: no login penalties for users behind the proxy (Dovecot counts per IP, thus a single user might lock out the whole user base behind the proxy, also an issue for large NAT networks), and especially of interest in your case: Dovecot does print the actual client IP instead of the proxy IP for several outputs; I'm not sure though how the client IP is transmitted and whether Nginx is doing so.

Comment: Thanks to clarify, I misread the doc. I tweaked Nginx's proxy script to pass client's IP to Dovecot using your suggested config pointing back to Nginx however does not seem to work.
Probably Nginx is not prepared to transfer client's IP properly.
I found a workaround though amending the script, filtering and recording necessary bits to a different log file.
Not the expected solution but works for now.

Comment: If you've got a solution, consider helping out others having the same problem by adding an answer on your own!

Comment: @Czollli please post your solution as an answer. It is perfectly fine to answer your own question and accept it.

Answer (score 1):

**Workaround**

Not finding suitable solution I rather created a new log file in the proxy script which provided a acceptable solution to the request.

Here is the excerpt:

```
$fp = fopen('/var/log/mail_logins.log', 'a');
$now = "[" . (new \DateTime())->format('Y-m-d H:i:s') . "]";
fwrite($fp, $now . " HTTP_AUTH_PROTOCOL: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTH_PROTOCOL"] . ", HTTP_AUTH_USER: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_AUTH_USER"] . ", HTTP_CLIENT_IP: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]. "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

It might help someone.

Answer (score 1):

Since version 1.19.8 (released 09 Mar 2021), nginx supports HAproxy's proxy protocol for all POP3/IMAP/SMTP proxied connections - you can enable it by setting `proxy_protocol on;` in relevant `server` or `mail` block. [Link to the nginx docs](http://nginx.org/en/docs/mail/ngx_mail_proxy_module.html#proxy_protocol).

Note that proxy protocol must be explicitly enabled on the receiving end (in dovecot), since it can't be auto-detected (in mail protocols, it's server who sends greeting message after connection is established, and if client speaks before the server - it's a protocol violation; while in HAproxy's proxy protocol it's the client (i.e. proxy connecting to the final server) who first sends the message about remote connection).

Also note that this question was asked ~4 years before this option was added, but to anyone looking for this in the future this information might be useful.